# Jquery code to get values from Json

Tags: jquery, json

I have to get value from the following Json data
`var mydata` prints the following

```
var mydata ={
    "_id": "524d1c36497c4d6f3c56bb84",
    "browser": "IE8",
    "id": "17",
    "jobs": [{
        "_id": "52450a0f8d8f5f6eee8bc606",
        "id": "34",
        "launch": "iuoiu",
        "names": "ioiuo",
        "params": [{
            "oi": "iuoiuo"
        }],
        "script": "panini-silk-flow"
    }],
    "mode": "daily",
    "os": "Vista 64",
    "server": "uuu"
}
```

currently am getting values

```
var os =mydata.os// getting Vista 64
var mode =mydata.mode// daily
```

but how can i get `names`  from `jobs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.each(mydata.jobs, function(key, value) {
        console.log(key);
        console.log(value);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `jobs` is an array, if there is only one job entry then access it via the index 0

```
mydata.jobs[0].names
```

If there are more then one job entry then you need to iterate through the list

Answer (score 1):

`jobs` is array of objects , and you seem to get item from array of objects, so do:

```
console.log(mydata.jobs[0].names); //first item from jobs array , i.e. jobs[0]
//or
console.log(mydata.jobs[0]['names']);
```

Answer (score 1):

If jobs is a list of jobs in the json, you can traverse it:

```
for(x in mydata.jobs)
    console.log(mydata.jobs[x].names);
```